# Can I use PIL imagegrab.grab() to screenshot a specific display?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I know I can get the main window, and my entire desktop, but I just want the ability to screenshot any one of my displays, and get the r g b values at an arbitrary location.

Is there something better to use?

Thanks.